# Helm unit tests - how to mock k8s entity for the "lookup" function?

Tags: unit-testing, kubernetes, helm3

Supposed I have the following condition in the template:

```
{{- if (lookup "apps/v1" "Deployment" "argocd" "argocd-server") }}
```

How can I mock this while testing a chart using [helm-unittest](https://github.com/lrills/helm-unittest) tool?

Comment: Which helm version are you using?

Comment: @MikolajS. helm v3

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used it myself for Helm unit testing but I think that's a good use-case for [KUTTL](https://kuttl.dev) they even have a dedicated documentation for [Helm testing](https://kuttl.dev/docs/testing/tips.html#helm-testing)

I assume a `TestSuite` would be rather short e.g. like the following where the `commando` blocks just bring in all the required resources:

```
apiVersion: kuttl.dev/v1beta1
kind: TestSuite
commands:
- command: kubectl create namespace argocd
- command: kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml
testDirs:
- ./test/integration
startKIND: true
kindNodeCache: true
```